# convert series returned by pandas.Series.value_counts to a dictionary

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to use pandas.Series.value_counts to get the frequency of values in a dataframe, so  I go through each column and get values_count , which gives me a series:

I am struggling to convert this resultant series to a dict:

```
 groupedData = newData.groupby('class')
for k, group in groupedData:
    dictClass[k] = {}
    for eachlabel in dataLabels:
        myobj = group[eachlabel].value_counts()
        for eachone in myobj:
            print type(myobj)
            print myobj
```

[image: The snippet]

what I need is a dict :

```
{'high': 3909 , 'average': 3688, 'less': '182 , 'veryless' : 62}
```

Answer (score 69, accepted):

If you want to convert a `Series` to a `dict`, you could call `dict` or `.to_dict()`:

```
>>> s
high        3909
average     3688
less         182
veryless      62
dtype: int64
>>> type(s)
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
>>> dict(s)
{'high': 3909, 'average': 3688, 'veryless': 62, 'less': 182}
>>> s.to_dict()
{'high': 3909, 'average': 3688, 'veryless': 62, 'less': 182}
```

Answer (score 13):

Extract keys and values for the dictionary from your_column and then zip it together.

```
values = df['your_column'].value_counts(dropna=False).keys().tolist()
counts = df['your_column'].value_counts(dropna=False).tolist()
value_dict = dict(zip(values, counts))
```

Comment: Please add description around your answer. It will be helpful future users.