# convert value_counts into a list of dictionaries

Tags: python, pandas

I have data in this form:

```
sbc['name'].value_counts()

Blue       353
Red        62
Orange     30
Green      27
White      20
Name: name, dtype: int64
```

But I need to convert it into this form:

```
"results": [
 { name: "Blue", "count": 353 }
 { name: "Red", "count": 62 },
 { name: "Orange", "count": 30 },
 { name: "Green", "count": 27 },
 { name: "white", "count": 20 }
]
```

I know I can use sbc[0] and sbc.index[0] etc but I don't know where to start.

Thans

Comment: Does this answer your question? [convert series returned by pandas.Series.value\_counts to a dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29403192/convert-series-returned-by-pandas-series-value-counts-to-a-dictionary)

Answer (score 1):

Extract the key-values lists and iterate over using `zip()`:

```
names = df['your_column'].value_counts(dropna=False).keys().tolist()
counts = df['your_column'].value_counts(dropna=False).tolist()

results = []

for name, count in zip(names, counts):
    results.append({"name": name, "count": count})

print(results)
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29403192/convert-series-returned-by-pandas-series-value-counts-to-a-dictionary)